# Get the group which has maximum number of records in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
[ID] [Name]   [Dept] 
--------------------
1     Manu      A   
2     Anu       A   
3     Tanu      A   
4     Danu      A   
5     Anu       B   
6     Danu      B   
7     Danu      C   
8     Anu       C   
9     Tanu      C   
10    John      C   
11    Anu       D   
12    Jane      D   
13    Danu      D
```

I need to get the Dept with maximum number of employees.

Here is what I tried

```
SELECT
    ID, Name, Dept
FROM
    (SELECT 
         *,
         rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Dept)
     FROM Emp) t
WHERE 
    rn = (SELECT MAX(rn) FROM t)
```

I need help in the `WHERE` clause.

Answer (score 2):

You need aggregation to count the number of employees.  The approach using `row_number()` is one approach, but with the right query:

```
SELECT Dept
FROM (SELECT Dept, COUNT(*) as cnt,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM Emp
     ) e
WHERE seqnum = 1;
```

However, a more common approach would just use `ORDER BY` and `TOP`:

```
SELECT TOP (1) Dept, COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM emp
GROUP BY Dept
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

If you wanted ties, then you would use `WITH TIES` in the `SELECT`.

Comment: Thank u that works. The approach using row_number() gives me only one Dept with max number of employees. But  what if more than one Dept has that max number of employees.

Comment: @BumbleBee . . . Use `top with ties` or `rank()`/`dense_rank()` instead of `row_number()`.

Answer (score 1):

No WHERE is needed. Try using a GROUP BY

```
SELECT COUNT(Name) as NameCount, Dept from Table
GROUP BY Dept
ORDER BY COUNT(Name) DESC
```

The biggest group(s) will be at the top

Results

```
NameCount | Dept
    4        A
    4        C
    3        D
    2        B
```

Comment: If there are more than one biggest group then ?

Comment: You didn't really specify in the question what should happen if 2 are the biggest. In this case the results would be A or C at the top with 4 followed by D with 3 and C with 2.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting all departments having the same max number of employees:

```
;WITH c -- create a list of depts and number of emp's 
     AS (SELECT deptid, 
            Count(*) cnt 
         FROM   emp 
         GROUP  BY deptid) 
SELECT d.* 
FROM   dept d 
   INNER JOIN c 
           ON d.deptid = c.deptid  
WHERE  c.cnt = (SELECT Max(cnt) 
            FROM   c)
```

Comment: It does, for my table structure, but you added your structure after I wrote this version ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, now you added the table structure:

```
;WITH c 
     AS (SELECT Dept, 
             Count(*) cnt 
         FROM   Emp 
         GROUP  BY Dept) 
SELECT c.* 
FROM   c 
WHERE  c.cnt = (SELECT Max(cnt) 
            FROM   c)
```

Comment: This query does. Thk u.

Answer (score 0):

I can't quite figure your table structure, but this selects the department with the most employees

```
SELECT * from Dept WHERE deptid = (
  SELECT TOP 1 deptid FROM employees
  GROUP BY deptid
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

)